# CFCServlet must be initialized

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have been trying to call a ColdFusion component from Java and following:

http://www.forta.com/misc/cfcproxy.htm

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html

Java version: **1.8.0_141**

I have added the required following jars in build path:

```
cfmx_bootstrap.jar
cfusion.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar ( Servlet jars added as on running java program it was throwing ClassNotFound errors )
```

After this added **Test.java**:

```
import coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.invoke().toString());
    }

    public String invoke() {
        String cfOp = null;
        try {

            // Instantiate CFC
            CFCProxy myCFC = new CFCProxy("D:\\practice\\cf_java.cfc", true);

            // Build arguments array
            Object[] myArgs = { "Java invocation!" };

            // invoke method from CFC. It returns a string.
            cfOp = (String) myCFC.invoke("getData", myArgs);

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return cfOp;
    }
}
```

Then added **Test.class** under **/JavaClass/**

**Application.cfc:**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset THIS.name = "CFTest">
    <cfset THIS.javaSettings = {
         LoadPaths = ["\JavaClass\"],
         reloadOnChange=true,
         watchInterval=10,
         reloadOnChange = true
    }>
</cfcomponent>
```

**cf_java.cfc:**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getData" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="msg" required="Yes">
        <cfreturn "I am alive!">
     </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

And finally ran Test.java as a java application and I am getting following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: CFCServlet must be initialized
    at coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy.<init>(CFCProxy.java:121)
    at coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy.<init>(CFCProxy.java:73)
    at Test.invoke(Test.java:15)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

Did I miss anything? Any suggestions!

Also, from the Adobe Docs:

> To call CFC, ColdFusion class loader must be the current class loader.

Can anyone please explain this or share some links?

Comment: "..must be the current class loader" That's the key. IMO it isn't as easy as the docs suggest. Steps #5&6 in the docs say to test the java class from *within* ColdFusion, where it would be the current class loader, and the proper servlet context, objects, etc... initialized. It'll work if you do that, but just running it from Eclipse.. won't.

Comment: @Ageax Yeah, that's working but what needs to be done for it to work on Eclipse?

Comment: Whenever I want ColdFusion code to be available to other languages, I add `access="remote"` to the function definitions.  That makes available as a web service.

Comment: @Beginner - I don't think you can... not easily. A CFC can't just be executed from a file path. It needs a CF servlet engine, or some portion of it, to do it's job, like java classes needs a running jvm to execute. So just importing the cfusion.jar isn't going to initialize all the objects it needs to work. That's why I said it isn't as simple as the docs suggest.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, that it is the option.

Comment: @Ageax Hmm, the option now is to call it as a web service.

Comment: @Beginner - Well, web services do avoid these kinds of dependencies and complexity. Either import consume the web service in Eclipse and invoke it (similar to using `createObject("webservice")`) or make an plain http call to the remote enabled cfc. As long as the CF server is running, it'll work.